# What XQuery expression will return the XPath of each found node?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I am looking for an example of a XQuery that returns the xpath for each node found. So for example instead of getting the text() of each found node I would like to get the path() - but that function doesn't seem to exist :-)

I see now that the XPath 3.0 spec defines a path() function that would do what i want, but apparently this is new to 3.0

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-xpath-functions-30-20111213/#func-path

Comment: Well there is nothing like "the xpath" for a node so you would first need to explain what kind of path you want to generate for a node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Martin Honnen commented, the XPath expression selecting a specific node isn't unique. For example, the second `y` element in the following document

```
<x>
  <y id="1"/>
  <y id="2"/>
</x>
```

could be selected (non-exclusively) by:

```
//y[2],
/x/y[2],
//*[@id = '2'],
/x/*[position() = last()]
```

If you are just interested in getting *some* XPath expression selecting the node, the [FunctX XQuery Function Library](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/) contains two functions that do that:

- [functx:path-to-node](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_path-to-node.html)
  returns an XPath expression that selects all nodes with the same name and
  ancestor names as the node you evaluate it for.

  In our example it would return `x/y` for both `y` elements (mind the missing leading slash).
- [functx:path-to-node-with-pos](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_path-to-node-with-pos.html) also includes the position of each ancestor in the document, thereby only selecting the node you pass in.

  In the example, the first `y` element would produce `x/y[1]` and the second one `x/y[2]`.

Comment: If you want to use the path to find the node using an XPath processor, then you will also need to think carefully about namespaces, because in general path expressions rely on externally-specified namespace declarations.

Comment: Thanks. I shall look at the FunctX library.

Comment: I looked at the FunctX library and using functx:path-to-node-with-pos (which depends on functx:index-of-node) works for what i want.